# Request goes through each line in dictionary: how to fix

Tags: python, dictionary

```
geomap = {
    "UK": ["London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"],
    "Czech Republic": ["Prague", "Brno", "Ostrava"],
    "Slovak Republic": ["Bratislava", "Košice"],
    "USA": ["Washington", "New York", "Detroit"],
    "Germany": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Munich"]
} 

search = input("Tell me city and I'll tell you country: ")

for country, cities in geomap.items():
  if search in cities:
    print(search, "found in", country)
  else: 
    print(search, "not found")
```

outcome:

```
London found in UK
London not found
London not found
London not found
London not found
```

Looks like it goes through each line in geomap dictionary. Do you have some ideas how to fix this? Thank you!

desired outcome:

```
London -> London found in UK (when IN dictionary)
Paris -> Paris not found (when not)
```

and no extra sentences

Comment: add a `break` statement ?

Comment: What do you expect? You're iterating over all key/value pairs in the dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question is a little broad and frankly quite poor. What output do you expect? What's wrong exactly? What have you tried to solve it? How do you think you should solve it? What do you need? `how to fix` isn't really a good question. The code you submitted as part of the question has no errors and works as intended. As mentioned by @Markus , you're iterating over all values in the dictionary and therefore you're getting an output for every value in the array.

Comment: hey guys :)) thanks a lot for your comments! i updated post with desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to break out the loop as soon as you find a match (after printing) or print one single message at the end if the city has not been found:

```
geomap = {
    "UK": ["London", "Manchester", "Liverpool"],
    "Czech Republic": ["Prague", "Brno", "Ostrava"],
    "Slovak Republic": ["Bratislava", "Košice"],
    "USA": ["Washington", "New York", "Detroit"],
    "Germany": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Munich"]
} 

search = input("Tell me city and I'll tell you country: ")

for country, cities in geomap.items():
  if search in cities:
    print(search, "found in", country)
    break
else:
    print(search, "not found")
```

Notice that the `else` does not align with the `if`. It is a `for/else` construct: the `else` branch is executed only if the loop exits without triggering any `break`.

There are a few other improvements you can make to the code (e.g. variable naming, printing arguments, etc. but that's more for the CodeReview SE).

Answer (score 1):

I adding break in the found in if statement will resolve the issue.

```
for country, cities in geomap.items():
    if search in cities:
        print(search, "found in", country)
        break
    else: 
        print(search, "not found")
```

Comment: thank you! but, unfortunately, it still doesn't work properly. e.g. if you search for Berlin, it gives the following: 

Berlin not found (4 times) and 
Berlin found in Germany

and it should say just "Berlin found in Germany" without any extra :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using your dictionary wrong. If you want to read a city and return a country you should try this snippet:

```py
geomap = {"London": "UK",
          "Manchester": "UK",
          "Prague": "Czech Republic"
          # all the other cities you need...
         }

search = input("Tell me city and I'll tell you country: ")

if search in geomap.keys():
    print(f"{search} found in {geomap[search]}")
else:
    print(f"{search} not found")
```